# Download and view document in ios from firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a firebase storage link of a document which I want to download in my ios device's Document directory and then view it from there using QuickLook Module.
I am able to download document in iOS device but it is not saving with the name i am providing.
I want to create following directory structure and then need to save document in "doc" folder.
Documents/chat/doc

following code is to create "/chat/doc" inside Iphone's Document directory. Where `folderName` will contain "/chat/doc".

```
    func createDocument(folderName: String ,completion: @escaping(Bool,String)->()){
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    if let documentsDirectory = path{
        //
        let docDirectoryPath =  documentsDirectory.appending(folderName)
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: docDirectoryPath) {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: docDirectoryPath,
                                                withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                attributes: nil)
                //return path on success
                completion(true,docDirectoryPath)
                return
            } catch {
                print("Error creating folder in documents dir: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false,error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }
        completion(true,docDirectoryPath)
    }
}
```

after creating folder i want to download document and need to store in newly created folder in Document Directory.

Following code will download document.

```
func downloadDocument(){

    createDocument(folderName: "/chat/doc") { (status, path) in
        if let docURL = self.documentURL{
            if status{
                //folder is created now download document

                let docDownloadRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: docURL)

                //get documents metadata from firebase to get document name
                docDownloadRef.getMetadata { metadata, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    } else {
                        //get document name from metadata

                        if let fileName = metadata?.name{

                            //create file system url to store document
                            let docsurl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

                            let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("chat/\(fileName)")

                            _ = docDownloadRef.write(toFile: myurl) { url, error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                                } else {
                                    // Local file URL for document is returned
                                    print("doc url \(url?.absoluteString)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }else{
                //folder is not created show document using online location
            }
        }
    }
}

Ultimate goal is to achieve something like this "Documents/chat/doc/abc.doc"
```

but my code is not storing document using file name it stores like this "Documents/chat/doc" where doc is considered as a document not a folder.

Please help to let me know what I am doing wrong. 
Thank you.

Comment: Where does a file go now?  And what does 'docsurl' point to?

Comment: @ElTomato docsurl is reference to Documents directory. And myurl is further addition to a path which points Documents/chat/filename.doc where i have to store my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating `url` at below line, here you are missing the path for `doc` folder.

```
let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("chat/\(fileName)")
```

This will save to `chat` folder. You need to pass the same folder while creating i.e `folderName: "/chat/doc"` so it should be

```
let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("chat/doc/\(fileName)")
```